Summing attribute values of multiple raster layers using ArcGIS Pro
I have multiple raster layers and I assigned a score to each raster layer. I'm using Esri ArcGIS Pro. For example, I have 4 raster layers:
Layer 1 Flood Risk: Areas with flood risk is 5 points; areas not in flood risk is 0 points
Layer 2 Wetlands: Lakes have 2 points; Freshwater Ponds have 5 points; Riverines have 15
points; Emergent wetlands have 20 points
Layer 3 Natural Lands: Natural lands have 5 points; Built/Developed lands have 0 points
Layer 4 303d Streams: 300 feet buffer around 303d Streams have 5 points; other areas have 0 points
I want to overlap these layers that produce an output raster with the sum of the scores. The areas with the highest scores are where I want to prioritize for protection.
I tried Raster Calculator to add the layers, but that just did an intersection of the layers. I want the raster output to display in total scores throughout the input boundary, not just the intersection and score of that intersection.
What tool should I be using and how do I produce a raster output that sums the scores?

What software are you using? Raster Calculator is available in QGIS and ArcGIS but they both work differently.

Raster Calculator will do this. Make sure all your layers have zeros instead of NoData across your entire area of interest (using Con and IsNull).
